# Prolog: ERROR: Undefined procedure: getval/2 How to use getval?

Tags: prolog

[I set the values of two variables in the first two lines of my code. However when I want to retrieve the values of them later using getval, I got the error  **ERROR: Undefined procedure: getval/2**. What's wrong?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq9TC.png)

Comment: obviously, getval/2 isn't defined

Comment: Check the documentation for whatever variant of Prolog you are using. Are you using ECLiPSe?

Comment: Also, please put the text of your code directly into your question. Do not use a link.